# objectbox DbMaxReadersExceededException

Tags: objectbox

ObjectBox version 2.7.1,
MaxNumReaders 500,
@Entity count over 50,
Some entities has over 100K rows.
Two weeks after release, we started getting errors in Sentry: Could not begin read transaction (maximum of read transactions reached)
How to diagnose a problem at an early stage with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit a DbMaxReadersExceededException, you can typically resolve the issue by check these options:

1. Because you already increased the max readers value, I assume you use multiple threads. The first thing I'd do is to **verify your threading logic**. We've seen cases where apps spawned threads without limits and thus breaking readers. Each thread requires a reader when accessing ObjectBox DB. Thus, getting a DbMaxReadersExceededException may be a symptom of a problem in your threading code.
2. If you have a lot of **short-lived threads**, you may see logs like "W/Box: Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread)" or "Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions". The latter hint is exactly what you should do before your thread exits. If you used only one or two `Box`es, you can call the method on the box: `box.closeThreadResources()`, otherwise the BoxStore also offers a method with the same name to do this for all Boxes.
3. There's also currently [an open issue](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/1000) related to unbound thread pools. If you run into that, the current workaround is to use thread pools with an upper limit.

Comment: We use multiple threads. If we call boxStore.diagnose() we see some readers count.
And we have this log
I/System.out: Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 69).
W/Box: Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread '')
W/Box: Destroyed recycled transaction from non-owner thread ''

Comment: I added a section on short-lived threads to the answer. Hope that helps you!